# Thoughts on how to solve this optimization problem using KKT?

Tags: optimization

I came across this optimization problem but I did not learn optimization theory previously. Could anyone provide some thoughts on how to solve them?

$
\begin{align}
  \text{minimize} & \quad e^{-\frac{{t_1}^2}{2}} + e^{-\frac{{t_2}^2}{2}} + e^{-\frac{{t_3}^2}{2}} - e^{-\frac{(t_1+t_2)^2}{2}} - e^{-\frac{(t_2+t_3)^2}{2}} + e^{-\frac{(t_1+t_2 + t_3)^2}{2}}\\
  \text{subject to} & \quad t_1 + t_2 + t_3 \leq K, \\
  & \quad t_1, t_2, t_3 \geq 0
\end{align}
$

Comment: Is there supposed to also be a $-\exp\left(-{(t_3+t_1)^2\over2}\right)$ term?

Comment: No, actually not.

Comment: It's a smooth function on a compact set.  The minimum occurs at a critical point in the interior, or at some point on the boundary.  Have you trie to find the critical points?

Comment: @AlexGao Here is an image of the [KKT-conditions](https://images.app.goo.gl/gTu7WZujdKfkERrK9). It can be seen that you have to be able to calculate the partial derivatives w.r.t. $t_1,t_2$ and $t_3$.